# pip finds package with search but won't install it

Tags: pip

When I run `pip search linkchecker` I get

```
linkchecker               - check websites and HTML documents for broken links
```

But when I try `pip install linkchecker` I get

```
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement linkchecker
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: That's odd. It's on [PyPI](http://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=linkchecker&submit=search). I tried using an explicit URL: `pip install http://pypi.python.org/pypi/linkchecker/7.5` and got this: `Cannot determine archive format of /tmp/pip-vRFtxt-build`. From this ticket, it appears that the only option is to use `setup.py`: http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3324146&group_id=1913&atid=101913

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`pip` uses `http://pypi.python.org/simple/<package name>` to look for download links, and this package points to a kind of "non-obvious" target. `pip` looks for tarballs/zips in the source page, but can't find a suitable url.

Use `-vvv` to see how pip looks for this package:

```
pip install linkchecker -vvv
```

You may realize http://pypi.python.org/simple/linkchecker/ points to http://sourceforge.net/projects/linkchecker/files/, and there is no `.tar.gz` as `href`, only as content, and pip can't handle it.

In this case you could try this:

```
pip install http://sourceforge.net/projects/linkchecker/files/latest/download?source=files#egg=linkchecker -vvvv
```

Comment: It would be nice to notify the package author about this installation issue.

Answer (score 5):

update pip first.

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

then, you can try install it again.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem for installing the ultramysql package from Github.
However, trying the proposed solution of [Hugo Tavares](https://stackoverflow.com/users/565999/hugo-tavares) still gave the same error.

What helped in my case was adding git+ in front of the url, resulsting in the following line of code:

```
sudo pip install git+https://github.com/esnme/ultramysql
```