# Why can't pip find packages listed in `pip search` results?

Tags: python, pip

First it's there:

```
$ pip search pylibpcap
pylibpcap                 - pylibpcap is a python module for the libpcap packet capture library.
```

Then it's not:

```
$ pip install pylibpcap
Downloading/unpacking pylibpcap
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pylibpcap
No distributions at all found for pylibpcap
Storing complete log in /home/u0/riley/.pip/pip.log
```

What gives? I realize there are other ways I can install this package, but why is pip doing this?

Comment: I've seen this happen before, too. For me it happened when calling pip from windows cmd.exe. I think in that case it wasn't parsing whitespace correctly. I however haven't seen it yet when calling from linux. From your shell prompt it looks like you are on a *nix?

Comment: Yes, I'm running Debian Squeeze.

Comment: Looks like you are not the only one.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9559716/pip-finds-package-with-search-but-wont-install-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pip found meta page that describes the package but it can't find valid download links on it.

The author of pylibpcap could put a link to the source tarball in the package's metadata on pypi or somewhere on its home page.

You could provide the tarball link manually as shown in [the answer that @mrchampe linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9578018/4279).

Answer (score 2):

This answer was meant to be a comment to J.F. Sebastian answer, as it builds on top of it, but it was difficult to copy and paste the content.

For folks who run at this problem as well and want a quick fix:

=> first, install libpcap

=> then:

```
sudo pip2 install http://ncu.dl.sourceforge.net/project/pylibpcap/pylibpcap/0.6.4/pylibpcap-0.6.4.tar.gz
```