# pip search AAP shows availability but pip install AAP will not succeed

Tags: python, pip

### A system tool installer question

Ah, I will post anyhow and yet

> [pip finds package with search but won't install it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9559716/pip-finds-package-with-search-but-wont-install-it)

suggests a similar question.

(adjunct tools for programming: so one might say; please advise if this is misposted here in Stackoverflow)

Well, this is a muddlesome puzzle for me. I expect to: be able to install A-A-P (probably also known as AAP or aap) using *pip*, and the reason I hope for this is that I use this command: (and get the following output)

**$ pip search AAP**

```
chinaapi                  - Python SDK For China API: Sina Weibo, QQ Weibo, Taobao, Renren, Douban
infi.hbaapi               - cross-platform bindings to FC-HBA APIs on Windows and Linux
shaape                    - Shaape - ascii art to image converter
AnyMetaAPI                - Support library for accessing AnyMeta-based websites from Python.
aesculaap                 - aesculaap - general purpose bot.
ckanext-dataapi           - CKAN Extension Data API - preview and access package resources through data transformation proxy service.
Aap                       - A portable build tool (make replacement) with internet support
paAPI                     - A python client for the Parallels Operations (POA) and Business Automation (PBA-E) APIs.
```

*Note how output is showing "Aap"*. However, the install fails. Here is how:

```
Downloading/unpacking Aap
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement Aap
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for Aap
Storing complete log in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

Thanks, and pythonic blessings on any help I can use.

Comment: Doesn't look like that package provide standard download links on pypi, which is probably why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long ago, in a galaxy not too far away, pip/pypi/setuptools used to scrape any linked site for what looked like download links.  It no longer does this.  So while Aap my have pip-installed in the past, it will not until the package maintainer puts a distribution on PyPI.